# I Need to make my kotlin jar application without sizeable border

Tags: kotlin, formborderstyle

im making a simple kotlin jar program and i need to make the border style like fixed single.

[Visual Basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7jWU.png)

i need to do that in kotlin (print is on visual basic)

Comment: What UI toolkit are you using? TornadoFX? AWT, Swing, JavaFX, FXML? Qt, SWT, Pivot, something else? Or is this for Android or iOS or some other platform?

Comment: i downloaded an java malicious analyzer source, and im testing it, idk what toolkit has used...